# Package clash in multilingual report

Tags: packages, chinese, russian, option-clash

I m workig on multilingual report. Below code is part of my code (Pls consider it as MWE). In the code below there is package clash error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \usepackage
                [russian]{babel}
```

Also chinese font cannot be printed. How can i avoid it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
  Это мой первый многоязычный докладе.
\newline
This is my first multilingual report.
\newline
这是我的第一个多语种的报告。
\end{document}
```

I m in great need. Pls help me out.

Comment: You include `inputenc` twice.

Comment: I have to include inputec twice since i have russian characters also. How can i use it once?

Comment: UTF-8 includes russian characters.

Comment: If i remove it, i get following error ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:这 not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: Chineese character does not get printed

Comment: This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem and add a little document, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem? Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[koi8-r,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\newenvironment{SChinese}{%
  \CJKfamily{gbsn}%
  \CJKtilde
  \CJKnospace}{}

\begin{document}

  Это мой первый многоязычный докладе.

This is my first multilingual report.

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
\begin{SChinese}
这是我的第一个多语种的报告。

\end{SChinese}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

and the same with `xelatex` (Code2000.ttf) is free availble in the net

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Code2000}
\begin{document}

  Это мой первый многоязычный докладе.

This is my first multilingual report.    

这是我的第一个多语种的报告。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pblm with my input is it has multilingual mixed text that i m fetching from database. i am not sue when will get chinese/english/russian text. So i want to generalize it.

Comment: then use `xeleatex` instead of `pdflatex` then you can mix the languages without any additional environment

Comment: This is my existing code, so i don't want to change my setup and installation. Pls guide me how to generalise my code for multiple language dynamically.

Comment: with `pdflatex` you cannot mix cjk languages with european languages without such additional environments

Comment: To be  more specfic, i m fetching data from database which has two combination (1) English & Chineese (2) English & Russian. I want to generate report for it dynamically and generalise it. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: if you know the language of your data it is really simple to put CJK into such an environment.

Answer (score 4):

Your example includes several packages twice.  Usually that is not a good idea and will cause problems.  Anyway, to address your specific question, you need to use the mechanisms of the CJK package; your system should include a useful example file `CJKutf8.tex` under the CJK documentation directory.  Additionally, you ought to tell latex which language different sections of the document are in, otherwise hyphenation will be inappropriate.  Here is a minimal example with your three languages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\newenvironment{SChinese}{%
  \CJKfamily{gbsn}%
  \CJKtilde
  \CJKnospace}{}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
  Это мой первый многоязычный докладе.

\selectlanguage{english}
This is my first multilingual report.

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
  \begin{SChinese}
    这是我的第一个多语种的报告。
  \end{SChinese}
\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: When i use Инфантильный гипертрофический стеноз привратника - это серьёзное  as russian text, i get following error message. ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.18 ...�ный гипертрофический 
                                                  стеноз привра...

Comment: Copy and pasting the above code plus your additional line into a new file here works fine with no complaints from `inputenc`.  Have you loaded other packages?  Is your distribution up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the appropriate place to put this.  When I began to use multiple scripts in my documents, I longed to find an MWE for each script.  I have compiled what I hope is an MWE in XeTeX for as many languages as I could.  I hope this is useful to others.  If you don't have `Arial Unicode MS`, just choose another Unicode font (like `Lucida Sans`).  It should compile regardless.  (Credit to omniglot.com for the phrase & translations.)

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}

% OPEN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

% SPECIFY UNICODE FONT

\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}

% SPECIFY ADDITIONAL FONTS FOR GLYPHS NOT INCLUDED IN UNICODE FONT

\newfontfamily{\Inuktitut}{Euphemia UCAS}
\newfontfamily{\Khmer}{Khmer MN}
\newfontfamily{\Sinhala}{Sinhala MN}

% BODY

\begin{longtable}{ll}
Afrikaans & My skeertuig is vol palings.\\
Albanian & Automjeti im është plot me ngjala.\\
Arabic (MSA) & حَوّامتي مُمْتِلئة بِأَنْقَلَيْسون\\
Armenian (E) & Իմ օդաթիռը լի է օձաձկերով\\
Armenian (W) & Իմ սաւառնակս օձաձկներով լեցուն է\\
Aromanian & Pãmporea-a mea-i ãmplinã di uhelji.\\
Azeri    & Hoverkraftimin içi ilan balıǧı ilə doludur.\\
Basque & Nire aerolabangailua aingirez beteta dago.\\
Belarusian & Маё судна на паветранай падушцы поўна вуграмі.\\
Bengali & আমার হভারক্রাফ্ট ইল-এ ভর্তি হয়ে গেছে\\
Bhojpuri & हमार मँडराये वाली जहाज सर्पमीनन से भरल ह\\
Breton & Leun gant sili eo ma dourruzer.\\
Bulgarian   & Корабът ми на въздушна възглавница е пълен със змиорки.\\
Catalan & El meu aerolliscador està ple d'anguiles.\\
Cebuano & Puno ug kasili ang akong hoberkrap.\\
Chamorro    & Bula håsuli/åsuli iyo-ku hovercraft.\\
Chinese (Cantonese) & 我隻氣墊船裝滿晒鱔\\
Chinese (Mandarin, Traditional) & 我的氣墊船充滿了鱔魚\\
Chinese (Mandarin, Simplified) & 我的气垫船充满了鳝鱼\\
Chinese (Taiwanese) & 我的氣墊船充滿了鱔魚\\
Cornish & Leun a sylli yw ow skath bargesi.\\
Corsican & U me battellu hè carcu d'anguili.\\
Croatian & Moja je lebdjelica puna jegulja.\\
Czech & Moje vznášedlo je plné úhořů.\\
Danish & Mit luftpudefartøj er fyldt med ål.\\
Dutch & Mijn luchtkussenboot zit vol paling.\\
Estonian & Mu hõljuk on angerjaid täis.\\
Faroese & Luftpútufar mítt er (skít)fult í álli!\\
Finnish & Ilmatyynyalukseni on täynnä ankeriaita.\\
French & Mon aéroglisseur est plein d'anguilles.\\
Frisian (N) & Min luftdümpetbüüdj as ful ma äil.\\
Frisian (W) & Myn hoverkreaft is fol fan Eels.\\
Friulian & Il gno hovercraft al è plen di bisats.\\
Galician & O meu aerodeslizador esta cheo de anguías.\\
Georgian & ჩემი ხომალდი საჰაერო ბალიშზე სავსეა გველთევზებით\\
German & Mein Luftkissenfahrzeug ist voller Aale.\\
Greek (Ancient)  & Τὸ πλοῖόν μου τὸ μετεωριζόμενον ἐστι πλῆρες ἐγχελέων\\
Greek (Modern) & Το Χόβερκράφτ μου είναι γεμάτο χέλια\\
Greenlandic & Umiatsiaasara pullattagaq nimerussanik ulikkaarpoq.\\
Hebrew & הרחפת שלי מלאה בצלופחים\\
Hindi    & मेरी मँडराने वाली नाव सर्पमीनों से भरी हैं\\
Hungarian & A légpárnás hajóm tele van angolnákkal.\\
Icelandic & Svifnökkvinn minn er fullur af álum.\\
Indonesian & Hovercraft saya penuh dengan belut.\\
Inuktitut & \Inuktitut ᐅᒥᐊᕐᔫᑉ ᐳᓪᓕᓕᒫᐸᒐ ᑕᑦᑕᕐᓂᖅ ᐊᒻᒪᔭᖅ\\
Irish (Gaelic) & Tá m'árthach foluaineach lán d'eascanna.\\
Italian & Il mio aeroscivolante è pieno di anguille.\\
Japanese & 私のホバークラフトは鰻でいっぱいです.\\
Khmer & \Khmer សុទ្ធតែឣន្ចងពេញទូកហាះយើង ។\\
Korean & 내 호버크라프트는 장어로 가득 차 있어요\\
Lakota Sioux & Iyéčhiŋkiŋyaŋka čha kiŋyáŋ mitȟáwa kiŋ hoká ožúla (yeló)!\\
Latin & Mea navis volitans anguillis plena est.\\
Latvian & Mans transportlīdzeklis uz gaisa spilvena ir pilns ar zušiem.\\
Lithuanian & Mano laivas su oro pagalve pilnas ungurių.\\
Low German & Mien Lüchtpöukaan ist vull von sük aalen.\\
Luxembourgish & Mäi Loftkësseboot ass voller Éilen.\\
Macedonian & Моето летачко возило е полно со јагули.\\
Manx (Gaelic) & Ta my haagh crowal lane dy astan.\\
Māori & Kī tōnu taku waka topaki i te tuna.\\
Malay & Hoverkraf saya penuh dengan belut.\\
Malayalam & എന്‍റെ പറക്കും-പേടകം നിറയെ വ്ളാങ്കുകളാണ്\\
Maltese & Il-hovercraft tiegħi hu mimli sallur.\\
Marathi & माझी होडी मासळयांनी भरली आहे\\
Mongolian & Миний агаарын даралтыг ашиглан хөвөгч усан онгоцийг дүүрэн могой загас юм.\\
Nahuatl & Noehēcatlapalqui cōāmichtēnqui.\\
Ndebele (N) & Isikepe sami sigcwele umzowa.\\
Norwegian & Luftputebåten min er full av ål.\\
Occitan & Mon aerolisador es plen d'anguilas.\\
Oriya & Mo hovercraft re eel bharti hei jaichi.\\
Persian (Farsi) & هاورکرافت من پر مارماهى است\\
Polish & Mój poduszkowiec jest pełen węgorzy.\\
Portuguese & Meu hovercraft está cheio de enguias.\\
Proto-Indo-European & Dihskolmos-to-h1me hxVnghel plh1nos h1esti.\\
Punjabi & ਮੇਰਾ ਹਵਰਕ੍ਰਾਫ਼ਤ ਨਾਂਗਾਂ ਨਾਲ਼ ਭਰਿਆ ਪਿਆ।\\
Quenya & Venenya vilyanirwanen ná quanta as angolingwi.\\
Romanian & Vehicolul meu pe pernă de aer e plin cu ţipari.\\
Russian & Моё судно на воздушной подушке полно угрей.\\
Samoan & Ua tumu la'u ato fagota i pusi.\\
Sardinian (Logudorese) & Su hovercraft est penu de ambidas.\\
Scottish Gaelic & Tha mo bhàta-foluaimein loma-làn easgannan.\\
Serbian & Мој ховеркрафт је пун јегуља.\\
Shona & Hovercraft yangu yakazara nemikunga.\\
Sinhala & \Sinhala මාගේ වායු පා යානයේ ආඳන් පිරී ඇත\\
Slovak & Moje vznášadlo je plné úhorov.\\
Slovenian & Moje vozilo na zračni blazini je polno jegulj.\\
Somali & Huufarkarafkayga waxaa ka buuxa eels.\\
Spanish & Mi aerodeslizador está lleno de anguilas.\\
Swahili & Gari langu linaloangama limejaa na mikunga.\\
Swedish & Min svävare är full med ål.\\
Swiss German & Mis Luftchüssiboot isch volle Aal.\\
Tagalog & Puno ng palos ang aking hoberkrap/hovercraft.\\
Tamil    & என் மிதவை நிறைய விலாங்கு மீன்கள்.\\
Telugu & నా హోవర్ఁక్రాఫ్ఠ్ అంతా ఈలు చేపలతో నిండిపోయింది.\\
Thai & โฮเวอร์คราฟท์ของผมเต็มไปด้วยปลาไหล.\\
Tibetan & ངའི་རླུང་འདེགས་གྲུ་གཟིངས་ནི་ཉ་མན་ལི་ཡིས་གང་གི་འདུག །\\
Tok Pisin & Bilong me hangamapim bot stap pulap maleo.\\
Tongan & Hoku vakapuna tētē 'i 'olunga fono 'i he toke.\\
Tsotsil & Li j-xulem tak'ine noj ta conoetik.\\
Turkish & Benim hovercraft yılan balığı dolu.\\
Tuvan & Мээң ховеркрафтым иштинде чылан ышкаш балык долу.\\
Ukrainian & Моє судно на повітряній подушці наповнене вуграми.\\
Uzbek & Mening kayiqim baliq bilan to'lgan.\\
Vietnamese & Tàu cánh ngầm của tôi đầy lươn.\\
Võro & Muq hõl'omismassin om angõrit täüs.\\
Welsh & Mae fy hofrenfad yn llawn llyswennod.\\
Yiddish & מיין פראָם ( שוועבשיף ) איז פֿול מיט ווענערס\\
Yorùbá & Ọkọ afategun-sare mi kun fun ẹja arọ.\\
Zulu & Umkhumbi wami ugcwele ngenyoka zemanzini.
\end{longtable}

% END

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that my focus is primarily placing words or small phrases within an English text.  For longer passages in other scripts, `polyglossia` is suggested, I think.