# inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode, languages, cyrillic, input-encodings

This is with ref to my previous question [Package clash in multilingual report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83293/package-clash-in-multilingual-report).

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\newenvironment{SChinese}{%
 \CJKfamily{gbsn}%
 \CJKtilde
 \CJKnospace}{}

 \begin{document}
 \selectlanguage{russian}
  Это мой первый многоязычный докладе.
  Инфантильный гипертрофический стеноз привратника - это серьёзное 
 \selectlanguage{english}
  This is my first multilingual report.

 \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
  \begin{SChinese}
    这是我的第一个多语种的报告。
  \end{SChinese}
  \end{CJK}

  \end{document}
```

when I try to compile it, I get following error message.

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [table].

(./data.aux
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/n' undefined (Font)         
using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.


! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with
LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

l.18 ...�ный гипертрофический стеноз привра...
```

How can I avoid such error message.

Comment: Try loading `fontenc` with `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}`. The `T2A` option is needed for Russian letters. Also note that `lmodern` doesn't load any cyrillic characters, hence the name "_Latin_ Modern" (if you didn't already know this).

Comment: I used \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} still same error message.

Comment: Your example compiles fine on my machine. I see you're using TeX Live 2011. Something seems to be acting funny with your fonts. I suggest upgrading to an updated version of TeX Live 2012. In the meantime, perhaps removing `\usepackage{lmodern}` might help?

Comment: I installed Tex Live 2012 and remove lmodern message but i m still getting same error message.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the "no-break space" character. Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}` to your preamble.

Comment: Did you copy and paste something into your text editor!?!?!? \shame on you!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8" error while trying to write a degree symbol (invisible character)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-error-while-trying-to-write-a-degree-symbol)

Comment: @AntalS-Z While the problem is similar, the space here is wanted.

Comment: I got this error when copying and pasting from MS Word. The solution is to delete and retype the offending characters immediately prior to the error.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The error you get is due to a "no-break space" character, according to what I can gather by copying an pasting your message.

This character is not usually set up by the `[utf8]` option and it's invisible to many editors, so it can slip in a document without the typist knowing it.

Solution: add in your preamble

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
```

if you don't mean to type a no-break space, or

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
```

if you want that the character stands for what its name says.

### UPDATE

Recent (after 2015-01-01) versions of the UTF8 configuration file for `inputenc` do define U+00A0 as `\nobreakspace`, so this should be of no concern, now.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my last comment. The `fffe` I got was put there by the command I used to see the encoding of the pasted text. Anyway, I cannot get the `00A0` either, so I hold my question. How did you came to it?

Comment: @JLDiaz Copy paste the error message; the conversion of the `char \u8:  not` bit gives the following sequence of Unicode points: `0063 0068 0061 0072 0020 005C 0075 0038 003A 00A0 0020 006E 006F 0074`, where you clearly see `00A0`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. That's what I did, but I got `0020` instead. I guess that my browser was "too smart" when copying characters to the clipboard. I pasted then at several Unicode converters online, and also in a terminal and used `xxd`, but I got always `0020` for the `00A0` char.

Comment: Does this solution also apply/work for `LuaLaTeX` ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You can use `\newunicodechar{^^a0}{~}` after loading `\usepackage{newunicodechar}`

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty What does `babel` have to do with this?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I had already gone crazy trying to find where the error lied, then gone crazy once again when I saw that deleting the problematic part *and writing it again, exactly like before* solved the problem... Invisible characters! Who'd have thought it would be something like that...!

Comment: @egreg Where did you find the unicode character code for LuaLaTeX ? My error message says : "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:édi not set up for use with LaTeX." I deduced from precedent discussions (but I could be wrong) that the symbol "é" is troublesome for LuaLaTeX. Can you help me ? And sorry for using this very old post of you, but this is the top google hit for this error message, and others are not helpful...

Comment: @Nicolas You don't load `inputenc` with LuaLaTeX

Comment: @egreg It works! I do thank you for your help!

Comment: A life saver. Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

As this is one of the top google hits for this error message, here's a more general answer with an example:

The cause is a unicode character in one of your input files that isn't mapped to an output.  This may -- especially if you're using the (unicode-supporting) biblatex/biber system -- be in your bibliography. This is a good place to look for errors as .bib files downloaded from publishers website are often malformed.  You can tell if the error comes from the bib file - the line number in the error message will be that of your `\end{document}`, which makes tracking down the actual error rather tricky (inspecting various aux files doesn't appear to help).

Some of these errors are subtle, like the non-breaking space in the question, or the hyphen (U+2010) character given to me by one journal, which looks *identical* to the hyphen-minus produced by the keyboard.

Copying the character after the hyphen and searching for it should help - unless your command window or editor "helps" by converting it to the more common equivalent or replacing unicode with blanks - in that case copy it from your .log and search all the input files.

(I'm happy to expand this in response to comments or watch it grow -- it's just an attempt to be helpful to searchers)

Comment: I often mistakenly type this character in ViM on Mac OS X by hitting ALT+SHIFT+SPACE, often after writing {\some-command ...}. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: It's a good strategy. It's often needed to clean the output files after fixing the problem.

Comment: That is one hell of a subtle error. I indeed had a hyphen (U+2010) instead of the hyphen-minus. Thanks.

Comment: How one may generally view what kind character is causing problems? In my case I somehow got U+FEFF 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (hunted down by modyfying file in git repository and using git diff - but is there a more general solution)?

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny for symbols that are invisible or very similar to existing ones it's tricky. Assuming an editor that supports different encodings (I use jEdit, notepad++)  if you don't otherwise use unicode, reloading (the log, tex, bib files) with a different (ASCII) encoding and looking for garbage can work. I have an idea for a script that might help - maybe I'll have time to fiddle with it later.

Comment: This olution is not ideal for me, in Polish accented characters are normal... Maybe hex editor would work? But it is a purely blind guess.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny, someone had solved this on SO for *nix. You can use [grep to give you the line number and highlight the offending character](stackoverflow.com/a/9395552/2583476) (note on my system you get two red missing character symbols per error by default, as my terminal isn't set up for unicode). The downside is that if you use unicode for accented characters they will show up as well. I'm still thinking about blocks and code points

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I know.  How much do you know about unicode? with Perl-compatible regular expressions in unicode mode it should be possible to define a range of characters that should work, but I don't know enough about Polish to help very much.  I assume you're using `\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}` to get your accented chars -- I do even though I use very few

Comment: Hopefully I will remember about it on the next trouble with unusual characters - I failed to notice that regexp would be helpful. "How much do you know about unicode?" - far more than I want :) But it is necessary given than in XXI century many programs/libraries still assume that text will be limited to ASCII (and many are completely unable to support characters outside ASCII).

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny here's something worth trying next time (an attempted whitelist): `grep --colour='auto' -P -n "(*UTF8)[^\p{Latin}-,.:()?#/\$_\d\\\ \*\{\}\[\]~;]" SPI_photodiode.tex`.  I'm told XeLaTeX is better for unicode support, but I don't use it myself. In general LaTeX support for unicode is not bad, but certain rare characters and control characters cause it to choke.  Spacing is a particular issue as you've seen.  While this question has become the go-to for the error message, maybe there's a more generic mystery-unicode troubleshooting question waiting to be asked.

Comment: Well, so far in all cases where LaTeX crashed on weird characters the weird character was anyway not supposed to be there. Main irritation for me is that in 2016 software still needs to be told to use utf8 (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`), but backward combatibility has its price.

Comment: Agreed, this is a general case as it could be many different unicode characters causing the issue. In a recent case it was `&lowast;` which interestingly is an HTML entity but for some reason needs to be declared as unicode `&#8727`.

Answer (score 32):

`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Ubuntu:

You must install `texlive-latex-extra` before use it.

Fedora:

You must install `texlive-collection-latexextra` before use it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). May be you can add which OS ? Ubuntu ? how to install ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/15925 for discussion of `utf8x`.

Comment: Yes, it's for Ubuntu.

Comment: Now I get "Unknown Unicode character"

Comment: @Geremia, please show string with this error

Comment: @Evgeny: ſ = U+017F = LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S. Utf8x recognizes what it is, but it prompts me to input a glyph for it. Am I having a font issue?

Comment: Thanks. I was using pandoc to convert markdown to pdf (which uses latex) and my convertion was crashing due to a &rarr; character. Installing the `texlive-latex-extra` package solved the problem.

Comment: This is the only right answer :)

Comment: @fedvasu: even if this is the only right answer, I still have problems with Emojis. Now what?

Answer (score 4):

I had two similar problems:

1. "`Unicode char \u8:` "
2. "`Unicode char \u8:.`" (with **dot**)

The problems were related to the .bib file (references list).

The first problem was solved based on the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }` stated by @egreg.

The second one was helped by the @Chris H 's answer.
I opened the generated file .log and looked for errors. I found:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:\C3. not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Then, I looked the "`\C3`" string in the generated file .bbl and I found out that the letter "`Ó`" (the first letter of an author's name, *Óscar* Oballe-Peinado) was the problem. So, I changed it in the bibliography file for `{\'{O}}` and voilà!

Despite I'm using "`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`", it seems not working specifically with the accented first letter of the first name of authors.

Comment: The name "Oscar" in Spanish doesn't carry an accent on the first syllable.

Comment: Ok, but that author really presents an accent:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Oscar_Oballe-Peinado

http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/15/8/20409

Answer (score 3):

You may get this error also if you use different language for bibtex.
In that case project.bbl may contain characters in different encoding (e.g latin2).

What you need to do is swap encoding when rendering bibliography to latin2 and switch back to utf8 after.

```
\inputencoding{latin2}
\bibliography{mybib}
\inputencoding{utf8}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is an answer to an (old) question. You should elaborate a little bit on your post and show a fully working example

Comment: I installed texlive-lang-czechslovak package to use slovak translations of entries in bibtex, but was getting errors while compiling project in utf8. I found out that it is caused by different encoding of .bbl file (evidently czechslovak package uses latin2 for .bbl files by default, bc. before using it I had no problems).

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I did save my `.tex` file with `utf8` but forgot to save also the `.bib` file with the same encoding (it was still in ANSI).

Instead of returning back to ANSI on my `.tex` file I just opened the `.bib` file with Notepad++ and chose to convert to `utf8`.

Then after compiling everything was working OK.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the same problem but none of the above answers solved it. In the end, I found the code `\'{\i}` in my .bib file. This was supposed to yield í but was producing a crazy unicode char that broke compilation. This .bib file was exported from CiteULike based on a reference that I entered mannually or copy-&-pasted from somewhere else. I suppose something wrong happened while converting a mannually entered/pasted í to `\'{i}`.

Answer (score 2):

If this happens in the bibliography, try specifying the language explicitly to bibtextu:

```
bibtextu -l ru my_paper_with_russian_bibliography
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this Error because I accidentally saved an included `.tex` file as ANSI while the master file was in UTF-8.

You can change file encoding in Notepad++ for example. But you will need to copy it from the the ANSI version and paste it into the UTF-8 version.

Answer (score 2):

[XeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) is more suitable than most other TeX engines for unicode : replace the lines

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and compile with `xelatex myfile.tex`.

Comment: You mean “XeTeX is more suitable than pdfTeX”, right? Because XeLaTeX is still *LaTeX*…

Comment: @clemens Thanks for the correction.  My bad, I had `latex` in mind.  `pdfTeX` would be too narrow though.  I hope the current formulation is better.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting

`% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode`

at the beginning of the file solved this issue for me.

Comment: didn't work for my case, where I wanted to render an unicode accent character from this author's name `Rui M´ximo`

Answer (score 1):

My error was related, but slightly different:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ╩│ (U+02B3)
```

or

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ß╡ë (U+1D49)  
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I had these errors because of a bibliographic entries generated in French babel which typesets the edition field, e.g. `1ʳᵉ éd.` or `3ᵉ éd.` using a raised re or e, resulting in `U+02B3` and `U+1D49` which apparently are not valid, even though (so far) all the other accented characters, e.g., **é** in **édition** are valid...

Because of my complex pandoc settings from Markdown with Libertine font, I don't want to swap to another *Tex engine...

So, my band-aid fix was to use the math mode to raise these letters:

```latex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D49}{$^\text{e}$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B3}{$^\text{r}$}
```

Also, if you're using pandoc, put them in your `header-includes:` part of the front matter.

Answer (score 0):

An anwser for a slightly different case:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ° (U+B0)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Here, the answer is very simple:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

This packages defines the `\textdegree` macro and also sets up `°` to use it.