# Nocite like command in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to have all my references printed on the PDF, the thing is that I only cite 1 of all the entries in the .bib file. And looking at the documentation on `biblatex` it says I have to use the following command:

```
\defbibentryset{hkeyi}{hkey1,key2,key3, …i}
```

But I do not understand the principal `<key>`, because from what I get all the rest `hkey1`, and so on, are the entries of the `.bib` file. Right?

I'm so used to using the `\nocite{*}` command in the traditional bibliography style and now I'm trying to move to `biblatex`. Is there any other possibility? Like it seems quite troublesome to dead with this package, do you think is worthy?

My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}


\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Ex.bib}

\begin{document}
 Some text 


\printbibliography 
\defbibentryset{*}{*}

 \end{document}
```

And the .bib file is the following

```
@book{Brezis,
title={Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential 
equations},
author={Brezis, Haim},
year={2010},
publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}


@inbook{sob1,
publisher = {Wiley-Blackwell},
author={Wiley-Blackwell},
isbn = {9781118032725},
title = {Sobolev Spaces of Functions of One Variable},
booktitle = {Applied Functional Analysis},
chapter = {7},
pages = {145-166},
doi = {10.1002/9781118032725.ch7},
url = 
{https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118032725.ch7},
 eprint = 
{https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118032725.ch7},
year = {2011},
keywords = {Sobolev spaces, functions, distributions, trace theorems, 
Hilbert space}
}

@book{Kub,
title={Essentials of measure theory},
author={Kubrusly, Carlos S},
year={2015},
publisher={Springer}
}

@book{grabinsky,
title={Teor{\'\i}a de la medida/por Guillermo Grabinsky.},
author={Grabinsky, Guillermo},
publisher={La prensas ciencias, UNAM}, 
year={2011}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be needing `\defbibentryset` if you don't want to define entry sets. In any case `\defbibentryset{*}{*}` should not do anything useful. `biblatex` knows `\nocite` and so `\nocite{*}` should do more or less the same thing as in BibTeX. Did you try it? What did not work as expected?

Comment: Yep I've tried before having the `\nocite{*}` before and after `\printbibliography` and it says that the command is undefined.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be undefined? And who says that? If you get an error message from TeX can you post it here in full, please? `\nocite{*}` definitely is not undefined. But there is a potential issue in the entry `grabinsky`: `biblatex`/Biber does not like `{\'\i}`, you should try `{\'i}` or even better `í` instead. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864

Comment: It says : Package inputenc: Unicode char' (U+301). Although it does the job, prints all the bibliography.

Comment: Note also that `author={Wiley-Blackwell},` in looks `sob1` odd. There is also little point in giving a full URL in the `eprint` field. Especially if it is the same URL as the one from the `url` field. I suggest you drop the `eprint` field in `sob1`. The author in `Kub` should probably be `author={Kubrusly, Carlos S.},` with a `.` after the S.

Comment: Yup, that is the `{\'\i}`'s fault. Use `í` instead or one of the other solutions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864

Comment: hahahahaha For sure, I was like thinking that * wasn't recognized or something. Thanks so much. Sorry. :(

Comment: So I need to check all the "spelling" coz all of them were given by springer bib generator. How do I know what kind of characters BibTex has problem with?

Comment: I extended my answer to explain that. The only real problem that many people seem to face is the `\i`. There is other stuff, but that would have to be looked at on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` knows `\nocite` and it works pretty much like its BibTeX counterpart. (The only difference that I'm aware of is that `biblatex`'s `\nocite` may also be used in the preamble. BibTeX normally wants it in the document body.)

You shouldn't be needing `\defbibentryset` if you don't want to define entry sets. In any case `\defbibentryset{*}{*}` should not do anything useful.

---

The real problem as confirmed in the comments here is the `{\'\i}` in `grabinsky`'s `Teor{\'\i}a`. See for example [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864), [Unicode -(U+301) error in biblatex, but not in main text: {\'{\i}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864). I suggest you use proper Unicode input and write

```
@book{grabinsky,
  title     = {Teoría de la medida},
  author    = {Grabinsky, Guillermo},
  publisher = {La prensas ciencias, UNAM}, 
  year      = {2011},
}
```

In general Biber accepts all valid Unicode input. Whether you can get a reasonable output from that depends on your TeX engine. pdfLaTeX only supports a limited subset of Unicode and may throw errors in certain cases. Some of these errors can be resolved by teaching LaTeX about the character (see for example [inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83440/35864)). The Unicode engines XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX shouldn't have those problems, but their willingness to print characters as expected depends on the font support for those characters.

Biber also understands many of the ASCII-macro replacements for Unicode characters (e.g. `\"a` or `\o`), but for reasons explained in the linked post `\'\i` or rather all constructions with `\i` are problematic. In general all accented characters without a precomposed form are problematic for pdfLaTeX, see [Why is caron treated differently than breve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170562/35864) and [inputenc error on special character in bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480740/35864).

Since you mention Springer-generated `.bib` entries I suggest you have a look at [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864). Often those entries give subpar results.

---

Note also that `author={Wiley-Blackwell},` in `sob1` looks  odd. There is also little point in giving a full URL in the `eprint` field. Especially if it is the same URL as the one from the `url` field. I suggest you drop the `eprint` field in `sob1`.

The author in `Kub` should probably be `author={Kubrusly, Carlos S.},` with a `.` after the `S`.