# bibtex file exported by Zotero contains bad character

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber, zotero

I use biblatex with biber. My bibliography is automatically exported by Zotero. My editor is texmaker on debian. Unfortunately characters are included into the bib file latex is unable to decode. I get the Error:
`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.`

How can I find the bad character, or what else can I do to prevent the problem?

**Edit: My Preamble**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,textgreek}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{biocon}         
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear, 
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    url=false,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=7,
    minbibnames=5,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist=false,
    firstinits=true
    ]
    {biblatex}
```

Comment: Depending on what the character is, it might be enough to just use ``\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}``.

Comment: Please have a look into your logfile: above your error message you should see the line causing the given error. There you will see the bad character ...

Comment: @Sverre: I already use that package...Is it possible that it conflicts with another package? I will add my preamble to the question.

Comment: @aldorado Your comment is a nice illustration of why we usually ask for MWEs ``:)``

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I systematically screened my bib file and found that it was a strange whitespace character causing the trouble - not visible in the normal editor. I found it after only one source was left and subsequent grep-ing for non-ascii characters....i will change to mendeley i guess.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/) seems to be about the same error message and one of the answers also includes biber, so its probably related.

quoted solution by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg): add in your preamble

`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }`

but of course, your case my differ. This was for the "no-break space" character. I suppose opening the .bib file in an editor that can switch between UTF8 and ANSI will help to find the problematic character.