# Scandinavian letters (ä and ö)

Tags: errors

I've been working on my thesis with MikTex, and I've had a problem for some time now. Every Ä and Ö letter is marked a black box of sort or as ?. I've looked around the internet and I know that you need to have

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

before you start writing. However when I try to use that, it gives me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textcurrency unavailable in encoding T1.
```

I'm using my university's template for the thesis, which has all the settings premade. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
```

are all set. 
Any clue or idea what is wrong?

Thank you.

edit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}



% ====== ASETETTAVIA PARAMETREJA / ALKAA ==========================


% ----------- K?ytt?j?rjestelm?st? riippuvat:


% UNIX:ia k?ytett?ess?:

% \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


% DOS-ymp?rist?ss?:

% \usepackage[cp850]{inputenc}


% Windows-ymp?rist?ss?:

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

% K?ytett?v?t makropakkaukset:

\usepackage[finnish]{babel} % Kieli: Suomi
\usepackage{times}      % Kirjasin: Roman Times
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}    % Postscript-kuvat kelpaavat

\usepackage[]{vmargin}      % Tarkempi marginaalien asettelu
\usepackage{url}        % Oikea tavutus URLeihin
\usepackage[]{longtable}    % Kun taulukko on pitk?

% Kappaleiden ulkoasu:

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\linespread{1.3}
\sloppy


\setpapersize{A4}       % Paperikoon valinta ja
%                      Tarkka marginaalien asetus vmargin paketilla
\setmarginsrb{35mm}{30mm}{30mm}{20mm}{0pt}{0mm}{12pt}{13mm}

\begin{document}

% ----------------- Tiivistelm? ------------------------------

% 150-200 sanaa pitk? tiivistelm?, jonka tulee mahtua yhdelle
% sivulle

Ohjelmistotuotanto pitää sisällään monen tyyppisiä ihmisiä. Ihmisillä on erilaiset persoonallisuustyypit, joita voidaan saada selville muun muassa MBTI:n avulla. MBTI:llä selvitetään, millaisia persoonallisuuspiirteitä ihmisellä on. Nämä piirteet voidaan jakaa neljään osaan: energisyys, tiedon saanti, päät?ksen teko sekä elämäntyyli. Ohjelmistotuotanto vetää puoleensa sellaisia ihmisiä, joiden persoonallisuustyyppi on sopiva kyseiselle alalle. Erityisesti ajatteluun perustuvat päätöksen tekijät ovat yleisiä yksilöitä ohjelmistotuotannossa, kun taas näiden vastakohdat ilmenevät ohjelmistotuotannossa harvemmin. Tietyn persoonallisuustyypin ihmiset sijoittuvat useimmiten tietynlaisille aloille ja työtehtäviin. Myös eri persoonallisuuspiirteet voivat joko heikentää tai parantaa sopivuutta tietynlaiseen työtehtävään. Tästä huolimatta, ohjelmistotuotanto vaatii monia erilaisia persoonallisuuspiirteitä omaavia henkilöitä työryhmiin, sillä eri näkökulmat ja monipuolisuus parantavat ohjelmiston laatua.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should provide us with more information. `epsfig` is really, really **outdated**. And as a German I would say, that Ä,Ö,Ü are not restricted to Scandinavian languages ;-)

Comment: The encoding you select for `inputenc` depends on which encoding your editor uses, they should match.  TeXworks for example, which is included in MikTeX, uses `utf8` as the default encoding (IIRC).

Comment: Have you tried setting the file manually to a different encoding (eg. Unicode)? I had a similar problem with cyrillic characters compiled with XeLaTeX, and fixed it by changing the default file encoding to unicode. I'm using Windows though, so I'm not sure how relevant this is if you're a Linux user.

Comment: I'm using Windows as well. Could you explain how to set file manually to different encoding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that this compiles to me means that there's something more going on.
If you have your editor configured to use utf8 this works perfectly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel} % Kieli: Suomi

\begin{document}

Ohjelmistotuotanto pitää sisällään monen tyyppisiä ihmisiä. Ihmisillä on
erilaiset persoonallisuustyypit, joita voidaan saada selville muun muassa
MBTI:n avulla. MBTI:llä selvitetään, millaisia persoonallisuuspiirteitä
ihmisellä on. Nämä piirteet voidaan jakaa neljään osaan: energisyys, tiedon
saanti, päät?ksen teko sekä elämäntyyli. Ohjelmistotuotanto vetää puoleensa
sellaisia ihmisiä, joiden persoonallisuustyyppi on sopiva kyseiselle
alalle. Erityisesti ajatteluun perustuvat päätöksen tekijät ovat yleisiä
yksilöitä ohjelmistotuotannossa, kun taas näiden vastakohdat ilmenevät
ohjelmistotuotannossa harvemmin. Tietyn persoonallisuustyypin ihmiset
sijoittuvat useimmiten tietynlaisille aloille ja työtehtäviin. Myös eri
persoonallisuuspiirteet voivat joko heikentää tai parantaa sopivuutta
tietynlaiseen työtehtävään. Tästä huolimatta, ohjelmistotuotanto vaatii
monia erilaisia persoonallisuuspiirteitä omaavia henkilöitä työryhmiin,
sillä eri näkökulmat ja monipuolisuus parantavat ohjelmiston laatua.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wait a moment...Now if I changed it to \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and checked the first section (where I retyped all ä's and ö's) it shows them properly! I just have to retype every ä and ö letter now I guess? Will see if it works.

Comment: Yes, it does work now. I just have to retype every single ä and ö letter. But in all honesty, I'll gladly do that if it now works. Thank you so much for the help everyone. This has been bugging me so much while trying to work on the thesis.

Comment: Don't, just use find and replace, copy an `ä` and replace with a letter `ä` written by you (it seems silly, but the same happens if you compile, copy from the pdf and recompile).

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis: Looks like your file contains a mix of UTF-8 and some other text encoding (most likely ISO-8859-1 or -15). There are tools to fix such messes (like, say, the [Encoding::FixLatin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encoding-FixLatin/lib/Encoding/FixLatin.pm) Perl module), but if your editor is showing both of them correctly, you may find that simply copy-pasting the text into another program (say, the Stack Exchange editor) and back again will fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The letter, which causes the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textcurrency unavailable in encoding T1.
```

is neither `Ä` nor `Ö` but `ä`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Ä Ö ä ö
\end{document}
```

And the output something like this

> [image: Result]

The reason is, that your input file is *not* encoded in `ansinew`, but UTF-8. If you want to continue with UTF-8, then use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

For an automatic encoding detection, see package [`selinput`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/selinput.pdf).

Comment: Like i said, utf8 doesn't work either. edit: apologies, didn't answer this post that I've tried utf8. :)

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis What's the result of using `selinput`?

Comment: Not sure if I used it correctly. I just wrote: \usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
adieresis={ä},
} and it still gives the same error: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:� not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis Then your input is UTF-8. The error message is a complete different error, maybe even unrelated to Scandinavian letters. For example, it can be caused by an non-break characters (fixed by `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{A0}{ }` or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{A0}{~}`). Try to identify the problematic line and character. The error message shows the error line and a hex viewer might help in finding the problematic characters.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis: Perhaps some invisible char like a non-breaking space crept in, or perhaps you are inputing a file with another encoding.

Comment: The error seems to be at line 196, which has the first ä letter in the sentence.

Comment: Perhaps the ä is not an ä but an "a + combining accent". Delete it and retype it.

Comment: I retyped every word that had ä's or ö's in the first section, and it still gives the error on line 196.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis If I had your file, then I could check line 196.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis: You can use an editor like BabelPad to check for unusual chars.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis You should post a proper minimal (may be non) working example.

Answer (score 3):

For the `\textcurrency` thing (it looks like a sputnik: ¤) you also need the package

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

in addition to the already mentioned packages

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % or \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} when using 8bit encoding
```

EDIT: Addendum: From the conversation I oversee that your encoding might be messed up (utf8 reinterpreted as latin1 or Windows encoding). This situation is known as "mojibake" and there is a python codec to fix this on PyPI here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-latin1-codec/2.0

Answer (score 2):

This works for me under Emacs/Linux with `utf8` encoding. If `ansinew` does not work for you, then `utf8` is perhaps the correct option.
If the editor uses a different encoding this most be specified. I can't test `ansinew`, since none of my editors on Linux support this (or I just don't know how to change it) and I don't use Windows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

Der schnelle braune  Fuchs springt über den faulen Hund

Äpfel -- apples

Öl    -- oil


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried utf8 instead of ansinew.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis: And what was the result?

Comment: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:� not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: @Gettingtiredofthis: Well, in this case, I assume, there is even more issue in your document

Comment: You might want to have a look at [my answer to *inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160051/28808) -- the � looks like a generic failure/substitute symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can also produce umlauts without any additional packages by using the control sequence `\"`. For example `Universit\"at` for 'Universität'.