# Error with utf8

Tags: input-encodings

i have problem.
My header look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

And when i want add tekst this diﬀerent, i'm getting message :

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ﬁ not set up for use with
>   LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H
>    for immediate help.... \item as a ﬁ

What is the reason of this problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: This may help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex

Comment: It is better to add f i as separate letters in the source and let TeX construct the ligature ﬁ

Comment: I also get this problem when using TeXShop. With
 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 

it works for me.