# "Unicode char \u8:‒ not set up for use with LaTeX."

Tags: unicode, characters

While trying to compile my latex document, I get the following error:

```
"Unicode char \u8:‒ not set up for use with LaTeX."
```

The line number associated to the error seems meaningless. It points to a line where there is definitly not the erroneous charachter. Even if I remove the line the error points to, the error still appears (at the same line number, even though the line content has changed due to the deletion).

So my question is: How can I find the erroneous character in my file? The file is huge, so I can't look manually through all lines.

Comment: The character is U+2012 FIGURE DASH. Just copy it from the log file and make a search in the file.

Comment: The character should be located at (or at least very near) the line included in the error message. My guess is a dash character.

Comment: thanks for the hint. just solved my issue: the erroneous character did not appear in the `.tex` file. It was in the `.bib` file! There I could simply search and replace it.
so my main issue was, that I looked in the wrong file all the time...

Comment: This comes up every now and then: I've flagged as a duplicate, because here's a previous version with a general answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160051/28808