# Why can't LaTeX convert this equation and display it in a PDF document?

Tags: math-mode

Why can't my Latex editor convert these equations below?

1. **(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) ∈ E**
2. **{(x,−2x,x)∣x∈R}**

**These are the codes I tried:**

1. `$(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) \in E$`
2. `$ \ {(x,−2x,x) \mid x \in R \ }$`

Comment: Type `{...}` in LaTeX needs `\{...\}` and the vertical line in Eq. (2) can use `\mid` to ensure necessary space.

Comment: I did the \{...\} thingy but it still gave me errors, hold on let me update my question to update my progress.

Comment: You might want to cite the specific error you get, as already mentioned number 2 should be `$\{ (x,-2x,x)\mid x\in R\}$`

Comment: I know why. Your minus (`−`) is not the standard ASCII `-`. And so is the vertical line.

Comment: There is also \lbrace and \rbrace.

Comment: Despite the title, this a very similar problem to [inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83440/28808)

Answer (score 21):

LaTeX does not silently fail, if there is an error it is reported on the terminal and log file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) \in E$

\end{document}
```

has terminal output

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file cc134.aux.

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 $(x,−
           2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) \in E$
?
```

Where the linebreak highlights the location of the error, and the message explains the problem that − is not known.

You could retype the expression with a normal ascii `-` character or declare the Unicode − to act like - with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\begin{document}

$(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) \in E$

\end{document}
```

runs with no error and produces

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When we are using Unicode math then we have no problem, because your character is Unicode minus. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

$(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) \in E$
\bye
```

gives expected result. Moreower, you can use the `∈` directly, if you know how to type it on your keyboard:

```
\fontfam[lm]

$(x,−2x,x)+(y,−2y,y)=(x+y,−2(x+y),x+y) ∈ E$
\bye
```

Comment: +1  I just "borrowed" this answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638701/1090 (I trust you to be a reliable source for optex syntax:-)