# Left \mapsto arrow

Tags: arrows, plain-tex

I am looking for a way to make a command for left version of `\mapsto` arrow with (AMS)TeX
.
This is what I tried to do:

```
\mathchardef\mapstochar="322F 
\def\leftmapsto{\leftarrow\mapstochar}
\def\longleftmapsto{\longleftarrow\mapstochar}
```

It "almost" works, if it were not for the 3/4 infinity sign that I get instead of the intended small vertical bar (1/3 of this one: |) that I need to place at the base of the left arrow. So I need the code for that little bar, since "322F gives me a wrong symbol.

Comment: I have removed the comment thread and edited the question to focus on the technical aspect being asked.

Comment: It is of course entirely reasonable to ask for answers focussed on Plain TeX (or OpTeX or ...), not just LaTeX. However, it is a long-standing convention on the site that alternative approaches, for example using ConTeXt or Plain for a LaTeX question, or here using LaTeX for a Plain question, are in-scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? I'm afraid it uses a package, however, since the font still has to be loaded somehow.  The font is documented [here](https://texdoc.org/pkg/stmaryrd) and the plain TeX version of it [here](https://texdoc.org/pkg/plstmary).

```
\input stmary %
$a \mapsfrom b$

$a \longmapsfrom b$
\bye
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That actually worked (after tons of loading of files). Can you get the long version of that, just like \longmapsto ?  Is stmary to do with the college, or ...?

Comment: The main problem of "pure Plain TeX" solutions (like is done when `\input stmary`) is that the fonts are loaded for 10pt size documents only. If you want to use such math in footnotes with smaller fonts, you must to reload all complicated font machinery for math again. Moreover, it is more complicated if you do not use Unicode math (where only single font with all math symbols and alphabets is loaded). For example, if the OpTeX solution is used then you can write `\typosize[11/13]` and all fonts are at 11pt size. And the control sequences `\mapsfrom` and `\longmapsfrom` are ready too.

Answer (score 3):

The characters are Unicode U+21A4 (`↤`) and U+27FB (`⟻`) Normally mapped to `\mapsto` and `\longmapsto` (which matches the HTML entity names) or you can just enter them directly as here.

[image]

Naturally you need a font that has these characters, That is set up in all reasonable tex formats, perhaps you'll prefer optex as being closer to plain syntax.

```
\fontfam[lm]

$ A ↤ B ⟻ C $

\bye
```

Or you could of course use plain tex directly with luatex or xetex and set up a suitable font (This is using latin modern math, process with the `optex` command)

Answer (score 0):

Logically speaking, since `\mapsto` and `\longmapsto` are available, so are their reflections.

Typographically speaking, this can be done via low-level PDF code. Conveniently, the `graphics` package has already done all the heavy-lifting, wrapping a great many lines of code into one time-saving easy-to-use command: `\reflectbox{...}`.

So, without requiring a special font, thus:

[image: shoulders of giants]

Simple tasks can be done in plain more or less straightforwardly, but wrapper-functions and concomitant complexity start evolving out of the code fairly quickly.

"Shoulders of giants", and all that.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

uiop $\mapsto$ \reflectbox{uiop}

uiop \reflectbox{$\mapsto$} \reflectbox{uiop}

\bigskip
qwerty $\longmapsto$ \reflectbox{qwerty}

qwerty \reflectbox{$\longmapsto$} \reflectbox{qwerty}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*

Based on the engine-independent solution at [Scale text (\scalebox) in Plain TeX/XeTeX to make it narrower](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517990/scale-text-scalebox-in-plain-tex-xetex-to-make-it-narrower), a plain version (pdftex, xetex, luatex) is:

MWE

```
\input graphicx.tex

uiop $\mapsto$ \reflectbox{uiop}
\par uiop \reflectbox{$\mapsto$} \reflectbox{uiop}
\par\bigskip
qwerty $\longmapsto$ \reflectbox{qwerty}
\par qwerty \reflectbox{$\longmapsto$} \reflectbox{qwerty}

\bye
```

[image: plain]

The linked question also gives a driver-specific version (`graphics.sty` plus `dvipdfmx.def`), manually coding up `\Gscale@start` and `\Gscale@end` (which insert the PDF literals), so that an `input` is not required.

---

For reference, here is a pdftex plain version of `reflect`, using its `\pdf...` primitives:

[image: pdftex]

MWE

```
pdftex

\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \pdfsave%
  \pdfsetmatrix{-1 0 0 1}\rlap{\copy0}\pdfrestore}%
    \hbox to --1\wd0{\kern--1\wd0\box2\hss}%
}

\rbox{abc $\mapsto $ xyz}

Text text text, $abc\mathbin{\rbox{$\mapsto$}} xyz$, text text text.

\bye
```

---

Xetex/Luatex:

[image: xetex]

MWE

```
xetex

\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal -1 0 0 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{\copy0}
\special{pdf:literal Q}}%
    \hbox to --1\wd0{\kern--1\wd0\box2\hss}%
}

\rbox{abc $\mapsto $ xyz}

Text text text, $abc\mathbin{\rbox{ $\mapsto$}}xyz$, text text text.
% note the space: >>\rbox{ $<<
\bye
```

Comment: Fair enough, but the OP specifically wanted a TeX solution, not LaTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes. I started doing a TeX reflect code block, but too much (3-4 days or more; beyond my resources). But the hint may spur others. It's not impossible, just long.

Comment: @AlanMunn Found a related question. See addition to answer.